# While starting a spring container with Cassandra configuration and Neo4j configuration, beans are getting mixed up for container

Tags: spring, neo4j, cassandra

```
I started up a spring container with both cassandra configuration and spring data neo4j configuration, but while starting up, following exception is noticed:

    Could not convert argument value of type [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultSessionFactory] to required type [org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory] exception

Any idea about why does this error occur?
```

> *I am simply trying to save a set of entities to Cassandra and Neo4j using the same spring container. The required configurations are
>   mentioned below. The bean name were qualified and in some case,
>   certain methods were overridden in Cassandra Configuration to no
>   avail. It was also seen that Neo4j is hard-coded to take the bean as
>   getSessionFactory.*

```
*Following are my configurations:*
```

### **Neo4j Configurations:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = { "com.*.repo"})
public class Neo4jConfig {

    @Resource
    Environment environment;


    @Bean(name="getSessionFactory")
    @Lazy
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(@Qualifier(value="neo4jConfigurationBean") 
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration) throws ConfigurationReadManagerFailureException {
        String[] packages = { "com.entity.store.reflection.state",
                "com.entity.store.reflection.base" };
        SessionFactory neo4jSessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, packages);
        neo4jSessionFactory.setLoadStrategy(LoadStrategy.SCHEMA_LOAD_STRATEGY);
        return neo4jSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="neo4jTransactionManager")
    @Lazy
    public Neo4jTransactionManager getTransactionManager(@Qualifier(value="getSessionFactory")SessionFactory sessionFactory) 
            throws ConfigurationReadManagerFailureException {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="getSession")
    @Lazy
    public Session getSession(@Qualifier(value="neo4jTransactionManager") Neo4jTransactionManager txManager) 
            throws ConfigurationReadManagerFailureException {
        return txManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }

    @Bean(name="neo4jConfigurationBean")
    @Lazy
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() throws ConfigurationReadManagerFailureException {
        ConfigurationSource config = new Neo4jConfigurationSource();
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(config)
                .build();
        return configuration;
    }

}
```

**Cassandra Configurations:**

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.*.repo"})
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Resource
    public Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {


        final CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        cluster.setSocketOptions( new SocketOptions()
        .setConnectTimeoutMillis(60000)
        .setReadTimeoutMillis(60000));
        cluster.setRetryPolicy(new CustomRetryPolicy(10, 10, 10));
        return cluster;
    }


    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        CassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new CassandraMappingContext();
        List<String> entityBasePackages=new ArrayList<String>();
        entityBasePackages.add(environment.getProperty("cassandra.package.entity"));
        mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(CassandraEntityClassScanner.scan(entityBasePackages));
        mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster().getObject(),getKeyspaceName()));
        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CassandraConverter converter() throws ClassNotFoundException  {


        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session()  { 
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
        try {
            session.setConverter(converter());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS);
        return session;
    }



    @Bean(name="cassandraTemplate")
    @Lazy
    public CassandraTemplate getCassandraTemplate() throws Exception {

        CassandraTemplate cop= new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
        CassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new CassandraMappingContext();
        mappingContext=(CassandraMappingContext) cop.getConverter().getMappingContext();
        mappingContext.setUserTypeResolver(new SimpleUserTypeResolver(cluster().getObject(),getKeyspaceName()));
        return cop;
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like that you mixing up the Cassandra Session with Neo4j Session - please add code that configures both

Comment: My system already have configuration for CassandraSessionFactory bean and Neo4jSessionFactory bean expllicity. Still the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue by implementing our own cassandra Configuration rather than extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration and the bean names used by Cassandra and Neo4j Session were same. While Neo4j is hardcoded to have getSession as the bean, AbstractCassandraConfiguration uses a same bean signature. When we implemented our own configuration, the issue was resolved and application worked without issue.